# Import table from HDFS in HBase

Tags: hbase, hdfs, apache-pig

I created a table in pig and stored it in hdfs:

```
STORE mapping INTO  'hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase/data/default/mapping' USING PigStorage ('\t');
```

Running the ls command on hdfs, I'm getting the table:

```
bin/hdfs dfs -ls /hbase/data/default
Found 1 item
drwxr-xr-x   - hfu supergroup          0 2015-11-09 13:33 /hbase/data/default/mapping
```

But while running the list command in HBase shell, the table doesn't appear.

I'm using:

```
hbase-0.98.0-hadoop2
hadoop-2.6.1
pig-0.15.0
```

all running on one virtual machine

**How can I import the table in HBase?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all create the table in HBase using HBaseHCatStorageHandler or directly from HBase shell.

```
CREATE TABLE meters (col1 STRING, col2 STRING) STORED BY 'org.apache.hcatalog.hbase.HBaseHCatStorageHandler' TBLPROPERTIES ( 'hbase.table.name' = 'meters', 'hbase.columns.mapping' = 'd:col2', 'hcat.hbase.output.bulkMode' = 'true' ) ;
```

col1- Will be the Rowkey of HBase table
col2- Will be the column qualifier under column family "d"

Now use `STORE` command to load data into this table.

Comment: I've created a HBase table from HBase shell and then I've tried to store the data from the pig table into HBase. But the store command in the pig shell stops after connecting to zookeeper: `[main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x150ec3d937d000a, negotiated timeout = 90000`

Comment: with Error "unable to store"